# Can't set headers after they are sent error in express.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, asynchronous

I'm implementing a create user function, which is posting the form data to firebase. The function works, firebase has received the data,  but my console shows the following error:

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Sometimes the error will not occur, I have found different solutions in Stack Overflow, but it doesn't work and I still cannot figure out which part of my code is problematic. Can any one help me?

```
var memberRef = firebase.database().ref("Membership");
//create new student record
function createNewStudentRecord(studnetInfo){
      var newRecord = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(studnetInfo));
      newRecord["status"] = "student";
      newRecord["create_date"] = getCurrentDate();
      memberRef.push(newRecord);
}


router.get('/studentTable', function(req, res, next) {
  var studentArr = [];
  memberRef.on('value',(snapshot)=>{
  var tableHeading = [];
  var tableContent = [];
  var StudentRecord = {};

  for(var uid in snapshot.val()){
    memberRef.child(uid).on('value',(snapshot)=>{
    var memberObject = snapshot.val();
    if(uid !== null){
      memberObject["uid"] = uid;
    }
    var memberStatus = memberObject["status"];
    if(memberStatus === 'student')
      studentArr.push(memberObject);
    })
  } 

    for(i in studentArr){
      var record = Object.create(StudentRecord);
      delete studentArr[i].password;
      for(props in studentArr[i]){
        record[props] = studentArr[i][props];
      }
      tableContent.push(record);
    }
    res.render("studentTable",{username:user.getUsername(),studentTableContent:tableContent});
  })
});

router.post('/studentTable/createNewEntries', function(req, res, next) {
  createNewStudentRecord(req.body)
  return res.redirect('/dashboard/studentTable');
});
```

Comment: What  does you express log say?

Comment: `memberRef.child(uid).on('value',(snapshot)=>{`  You have an async issue, basically this is getting fired after you have sent `res.render("`

Comment: Do you mean the error message?

Comment: @Keith I haven't learnt async yet, can you tell me how to fix the bug?